# Tailwind width classes not working when mapped to component due to style purging

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a react component with the following code:

```js
function DoubleCell(props: Props) {
    return (
        <div className="DoubleCell flex w-2/3 mx-auto">
            <div className={`formula_dbl ${props.formula_width ? `w-${props.formula_width}` : "w-1/2"}`}>
                {props.formula}
            </div>

            <div className={`desc_dbl ${props.description_width? `w-${props.description_width}`:"w-1/2"}`}>
                {props.description}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It is basically a div taking 2 thirds of a screen width with 2 nested divs inside. Their contents are defined elsewhere when they are called as a component. Now one interesting thing is that I want the nested divs to optionally have their widths defined...

Here is my Props interface.

```js
interface Props {
    formula: String;
    description: String;
    formula_width?: String;
    description_width?: String;
}
```

All of this is code is present in `components/FormulaCell.tsx`

---

Here is my `_app.tsx` file where I start calling the component:

```js
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import DoubleCell from "./components/FormulaCell"

const formulae = [
    ["f1","f1-uses","5/6", "1/6"],
    ["f2","f2-uses","4/6", "2/6"],
    ["f3","f3-uses","3/6", "3/6"],
    ["f4","f4-uses","2/6", "4/6"],
    ["f5","f5-uses","1/6", "5/6"],
]

function App(){
    return (
        <>
            {formulae.map((formula, index) => (
                <DoubleCell
                key={index}
                formula={formula[0]}
                description={formula[1]}
                formula_width={formula[2]}
                description_width={formula[3]}/>
        ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

In the above code where I defined the array of values to be used as parameters for the `<DoubleCell/>` component...

```py
["f1","f1-uses","5/6", "1/6"],
["f2","f2-uses","4/6", "2/6"],
["f3","f3-uses","3/6", "3/6"],
["f4","f4-uses","2/6", "4/6"],
["f5","f5-uses","1/6", "5/6"]
```

The content (`eg: f1` and `f1-uses`) works, but the tailwind width classes don't work.

---

I tried look for a solution to this problem and found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907369/color-classes-of-tailwind-css-not-working-when-appended)

Where they said that styles were being removed by tailwind as they were not used, and that they had created an invisible div with the required classes for tailwind to load them. The problem is that my project will soon use Arbitrary values, which I many not be able to put in an invisible div (as it can be literally anything).

---

Comment: What happens if you enable [JIT](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) in the tailwind config?

Comment: @heaxyh unfortunately `JIT` makes no difference, and yes, I did configure my purge like so: `purge: ['./src/**/*.js', './src/**/*.jsx', './src/**/*.ts', './src/**/*.tsx', './public/**/*.html','./src/*',]`.

Answer (score 1):

A [tip](https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1638695713793011712) from the author of tailwindcss:

> Useful trick if you ever need to use inline styles because a value is coming from the database or something but also need to change those styles on hover or similar —
>
> Use those values to set CSS variables using inline styles, then use arbitrary values to read the variables

```
<div
  style={{
    '--custom-width': width,
  }}
  className="w-[var(--custom-width)]"
>
```

Comment: style={{'--custom-width': props.description_width}} className={desc_dbl ${props.description_width ? `w-[var(--custom-width)]` : "w-1/2" }} shoved this into my code and get ts error 2322 Type '{ '--custom-width': String | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'. @zouabi

Comment: Oh yeah,  I think I used to fix it with `style={{ ('--custom-width' as any): props.description_width}}` I think.

Comment: nope. `Parsing error: Property assignment expected.` and `Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?ts(1381)`

Comment: Then you'd have to `any` the whole object: `<div style={{ '--custom-width': props.description_width } as any}></div>`